# convert nested list to list format in scala

Tags: scala

I want to convert below list to another list. can someone help me to get desired o/p

```
List((kohli,List(scores1:02:55,kohli1:03:31))
    ,(Rohit,List(sco1:02:55,kohli1:03:31))
    ,(dhawan,List(scoresmade1:02:55,kohli1:03:31)))
```

**Expected format**

```
List((kohli,(scores1:02:55,kohli1:03:31))
    ,(Rohit,(sco1:02:55,kohli1:03:31))
    ,(dhawan,(scoresmade1:02:55,kohli1:03:31)))
```

Comment: What should happen if the inner `List` has more than or less than 2 elements? What is the type of your desired result? It looks like `List[(String,(String,String))]`. What's the purpose/point of the inner tuple?

Comment: it is in the form of List(String,(String,String)). I am using this result down the the line.

Comment: `List` is more flexible that a tuple if all the items are the same type, so you might want to consider keeping the `List` and modifying your downstream code, especially if you want to handle more elements in the list/tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to go about it.

```
List(("kohli",  List("scores1:02:55", "kohli1:03:31"))
    ,("Rohit",  List("sco1:02:55", "kohli1:03:31"))
    ,("dhawan", List("scoresmade1:02:55", "kohli1:03:31")))
  .map{
    case (str, s1::s2::_) => (str, (s1, s2))
    case (str, s1::Nil)   => (str, (s1, ""))
    case (str, Nil)       => (str, ("", ""))
  }
//res0: List[(String, (String, String))] = List((kohli,(scores1:02:55,kohli1:03:31))
//                                            , (Rohit,(sco1:02:55,kohli1:03:31))
//                                            , (dhawan,(scoresmade1:02:55,kohli1:03:31)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and it is working. In case if we have more values inner List then it is difficult to write s1::s2:: etc. Is there another way to get it done

Comment: There is no easy/simple conversion from `List` to `Tuple`. The two serve very different purposes and are, essentially, unrelated. Trying to go back-and-forth between them would be a code smell, a strong indication that you should rethink your data structures. If the answer was useful then you might accept it and/or up-vote it.